# Radio button and checkbox problems

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I have this piece of code:

```
<div class="grey-bg box-top-fix">
  <h4>Item 1</h4>
  <p class="muted-small tempos">From 40 $</p>
  <div class="aboutsocial">
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="ws_type" value="1">
      Choose this option </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to change add this class (grey-bg-selected) into my first  (the one with the grey-bg box-top-fix classes).

I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.grey-bg').click(function() {
      $('.grey-bg').removeClass('grey-bg-selected')
      $(this).addClass('grey-bg-selected')
  });
});
```

I have two problems:

1/ If I do not click on the radio button my parent box take the new class. I want this only if the radio is checked. If the radio button lost the check, remove the class.
[See the jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pV2E3/1/)

2/ With checkbox, it doesn't work because if I click on another checkbox, the first lost the new class.
[See the jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mxwyp/)

Could you please help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd swear I saw this question earlier today. Anyway, don't you want radio buttons, not checkboxes?

Comment: I need both. Yes I change a little bit my question to be more readable.

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3qAQV/

Comment: Take a look at : http://jsfiddle.net/Mxwyp/1/ It's doing what you want I think

Comment: Thanks MatRt and j08691.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand when you want the class to be added, but if it's when the radio button is clicked, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
      $('.grey-bg').removeClass('grey-bg-selected')
      $(this).parents('.grey-bg').addClass('grey-bg-selected')
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks it solves my first question. Do you have any suggestions for the second point ?

Comment: It all depends on how you set up the HTML in the page, if the structure is the same then just change `$('input[type=radio]')` to `$('input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]')`

Answer (score 0):

On a second click on a checkbox, the first lost the class because you are removing the class of all area with `$('.grey-bg').removeClass('grey-bg-selected')`

Take a look at : [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mxwyp/1) It's doing what you want I think

Comment: Thanks. How can I merge the two script (case 1 and 2)?

Comment: I don't understand your need to "merge". My example use checkbox that allow you to check multiple entries. The example of @j08691 use radio button that allow you to choose only one entry. So, you juste have to select the solution you want.